# null pointer exception while autowiring

Tags: model-view-controller, spring-security, nullpointerexception, autowired

Hi i am getting null pointer exception while I try to autowire from my Export Excel class to Back office controller but the other way round is working .  please help me I need to fetch the data from my back office controller....
below is my code snippet

**this is my ExportExcelView**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractExcelView;

import com.rectrix.exide.controller.BackOfficeController;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.QuestionBankDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.service.ModuleService;
@Configuration
@Component
@Repository
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExportExcelView extends AbstractExcelView {

    private BackOfficeController backOfficeController;


    public BackOfficeController getBackOfficeController() {
        return backOfficeController;
    }

    @Resource(name="backOfficeController")
    public void setBackOfficeController(BackOfficeController backOfficeController) {
        this.backOfficeController = backOfficeController;
    }

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExportExcelView.class);
    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String value=(String) model.get("excel");


        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("questionbankupload")){
                        /* List<QuestionBankDetails> list=(List<QuestionBankDetails> )model.get("transactiondata");*/
                         HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet("Question Bank Excel");
                         setExcelForQuestionBankUpload(excelSheet/*,list*/);                            
                                }

        }
        public void setExcelForQuestionBankUpload(HSSFSheet excelSheet/*, List<QuestionBankDetails> list*/) {


        HSSFRow excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(0);
        excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue("QUESTION");
        excelHeader.createCell(1).setCellValue("OPT1");
        excelHeader.createCell(2).setCellValue("OPT2");
        excelHeader.createCell(3).setCellValue("OPT3");
        excelHeader.createCell(4).setCellValue("OPT4");
        excelHeader.createCell(5).setCellValue("OPT5");
        excelHeader.createCell(6).setCellValue("CORRECT_ANSWER_OPTION");
        excelHeader.createCell(7).setCellValue("QUESTION_TYPE");
        excelHeader.createCell(8).setCellValue("SECTION_ID");
        excelHeader.createCell(9).setCellValue("LEVEL");

        // just for try
        List<QuestionBankDetails> list = new ArrayList<QuestionBankDetails>();

        try {
            list=backOfficeController.toGet();  // from this part my code is not going to controller
                    int i=1;
            for(QuestionBankDetails qd : list) {

                excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(i++);
                    excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue(qd.getQuestion());
                    excelHeader.createCell(1).setCellValue(qd.getOpt1());
                    excelHeader.createCell(2).setCellValue(qd.getOpt2());
                    excelHeader.createCell(3).setCellValue(qd.getOpt3());
                    excelHeader.createCell(4).setCellValue(qd.getOpt4());
                    excelHeader.createCell(5).setCellValue(qd.getOpt5());
                    excelHeader.createCell(6).setCellValue(qd.getCorrectAnswer());
                    excelHeader.createCell(7).setCellValue(qd.getQuestionType());
                    excelHeader.createCell(8).setCellValue(qd.getSectionId());
                    excelHeader.createCell(9).setCellValue(qd.getLevel());
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
}

}
```

**This is my Controller  (back office controller)**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.management.relation.Role;
import javax.resource.spi.AdministeredObject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.Public;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.Batch;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import sun.security.jca.GetInstance;

import com.rectrix.exide.dao.LanguageDetailsDao;
import com.rectrix.exide.dao.RoleDetailsDao;
import com.rectrix.exide.dao.SlotDao;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.BatchNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.DuplicateFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.EmployeeIdNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.GroupNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.LanguageNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.ModuleNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.RoleNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.exception.TopicNotFound;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.AddConfigDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.AddToModuleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.AddVariable;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.AttendanceDetailsForm;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.CreateBatchDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.CreateModuleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.DummyModel;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.EditModuleAdminDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.EmployeeDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.EmployeeFormDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.ExternalUploadDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.InternalUploadDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.LangDetailsForm;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.ListAdminDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.ListModuleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.QuestionBankDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.RoleModuleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.SectionDetailsForm;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.SessionStoreDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.SlotForm;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.TopicDetailsForm;
import com.rectrix.exide.form.model.TopicSectionCountDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.hris.model.EmployeeMasterLookUp;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.BatchDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.GroupMaster;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.LanguageDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.LoginUserDetail;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.ModuleConfigDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.RoleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.Slot;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.StudentDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.model.ModuleDetails;
import com.rectrix.exide.service.AttendanceService;
import com.rectrix.exide.service.BatchService;
import com.rectrix.exide.service.ModuleService;
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.resources.motif;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;
import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.recompile;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.EmptySerializer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/")
@Component
@ComponentScan

public class BackOfficeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BackOfficeController.class);



    public BackOfficeController() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Autowired
    private ModuleService moduleService;



    @RequestMapping(value="questionuploadtemplate", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getQuestionUploadTemplate(){
        return new ModelAndView("ExportExcel","excel","questionbankupload");
    }



@RequestMapping(value="listquestions",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public @ResponseBody List<QuestionBankDetails> getQuestionListByTopicId(@RequestParam String topicId, @RequestParam String langId, @RequestParam Long moduleId){
        List<QuestionBankDetails>list = new ArrayList<QuestionBankDetails>();
        try {

            /*String topicId = "1";
                        String langId = "l1";
                        Long moduleId =  (long)1;*/
            list = moduleService.getQuestionListByTopicId(topicId, langId, new Long(moduleId));
            return list;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error in fetching the questions from the topic id", e);
        }
        return list;

    }





public List<QuestionBankDetails> toGet(){

        List<QuestionBankDetails> list = new ArrayList<QuestionBankDetails>();
        try {
            String topicId ="1";
            String langId ="l1";
            Long moduleId =(long)1;
            list=getQuestionListByTopicId(topicId, langId, new Long(moduleId));
            return list;

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return new ArrayList<QuestionBankDetails>();
    } 

  }
```

**This is my bean**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rectrix.exide.controller"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:system.properties" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="${spring.view.prefix}" /> <property name="suffix" 
        value="${spring.view.suffix}" /> </bean>



    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
     <property name="location">
         <value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/spring-excel-views.xml</value>
     </property>
     <property name="order" value="0" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="excelExport" class="com.rectrix.exide.excel.ExportExcelView">
  <property name="backOfficeController" ref="backOfficeController"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="backOfficeController" class="com.rectrix.exide.controller.BackOfficeController"/> 



    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />



</beans>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting anything into your view. The data should be in the model. The model should be properly prepared by the controller. The task of the view is to use the model to render itself. It shouldn't be burdened with anything else. Next to that your configuration and classes are a mess, you really need to clean up things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is a mess. First fix your classes..

```
public class ExportExcelView extends AbstractExcelView { ... }
```

Remove all those annotations.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/")
public class BackOfficeController { ... }
```

`@Component` and `@ComponentScan` don't make sense here.

Cleanup your xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rectrix.exide.controller" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:system.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="${spring.view.prefix}" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value="${spring.view.suffix}" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/META-INF/spring/spring-excel-views.xml" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that your excel based view is also defined in the `spring-excel-views.xml`!

However the real question is why on earth are you injecting the controller in the view? The view should only use the model to render itself. It shouldn't do anything else. Instead of injecting the controller into the view you should prepare the model properly.

Your view should be like this.

```
public class ExportExcelView extends AbstractExcelView {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExportExcelView.class);

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String value=(String) model.get("excel");

        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("questionbankupload")){
            /* List<QuestionBankDetails> list=(List<QuestionBankDetails> )model.get("transactiondata");*/
            HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet("Question Bank Excel");
            setExcelForQuestionBankUpload(excelSheet, model);                            
        }        
    }

    public void setExcelForQuestionBankUpload(HSSFSheet excelSheet, model) {

        HSSFRow excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(0);
        excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue("QUESTION");
        excelHeader.createCell(1).setCellValue("OPT1");
        excelHeader.createCell(2).setCellValue("OPT2");
        excelHeader.createCell(3).setCellValue("OPT3");
        excelHeader.createCell(4).setCellValue("OPT4");
        excelHeader.createCell(5).setCellValue("OPT5");
        excelHeader.createCell(6).setCellValue("CORRECT_ANSWER_OPTION");
        excelHeader.createCell(7).setCellValue("QUESTION_TYPE");
        excelHeader.createCell(8).setCellValue("SECTION_ID");
        excelHeader.createCell(9).setCellValue("LEVEL");

        // just for try
        List<QuestionBankDetails> list = model.get("details");

        try {
            int i=1;
            for(QuestionBankDetails qd : list) {
                excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(i++);
                excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue(qd.getQuestion());
                excelHeader.createCell(1).setCellValue(qd.getOpt1());
                excelHeader.createCell(2).setCellValue(qd.getOpt2());
                excelHeader.createCell(3).setCellValue(qd.getOpt3());
                excelHeader.createCell(4).setCellValue(qd.getOpt4());
                excelHeader.createCell(5).setCellValue(qd.getOpt5());
                excelHeader.createCell(6).setCellValue(qd.getCorrectAnswer());
                excelHeader.createCell(7).setCellValue(qd.getQuestionType());
                excelHeader.createCell(8).setCellValue(qd.getSectionId());
                excelHeader.createCell(9).setCellValue(qd.getLevel());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and your controller should prepare the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value="questionuploadtemplate", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getQuestionUploadTemplate(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("ExportExcel");
    mav.addObject("excel", "questionbankupload");
    mav.addObject("details", doGet());
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I am new to springs. your solution worked in my project. can you please tell me as in what is the best way of learning springs and MVC. I am getting confused day by day. I am working in a project where they give me task for the day, and with great difficulty I search in google and implement it in my project... Please help me and show me the best way of learning the technologies fast..... Thank you once again